# Updating custom customer attribute

Tags: magento2

I want to make one of customer attributes not required

I run the below code, but it doesn't work

```
   public function upgrade(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
{
        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
        $customerSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY,
            'trade_license',
            [
                'required' => false
            ]
        );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following code to update customer attribute

```
public function upgrade(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
{
    $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

    // Define the attribute code
    $attributeCode = 'trade_license';

    // Update the attribute
    $customerSetup->updateAttribute(
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY,
        $attributeCode,
        'is_required',
        false
    );

    // Remove any validation rules that make it required
    $customerSetup->updateAttribute(
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY,
        $attributeCode,
        'validate_rules',
        ''
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think **addAttribute()** is not for the update the attribute

you can follow this [link](https://webkul.com/blog/update-product-custom-attribute-scope-in-magento-2/)